# How to get RenderingInfo from an Event Log Record?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, wmi, event-log

I've been trying to find different ways to retrieve events from a remote server. Currently we're using Wevtutil.exe but latency between the server is making the tool very slow (~90 events/s).

C#'s EventLogQuery / EventLogReader / EventLogRecord extracts events much quicker (~5800 events/s), but the output is missing the RenderingInfo of the event. EventLogRecord's [ToXml()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord.toxml(v=vs.110).aspx) method says the output will conform to the Event Schema, [which has RenderingInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384343.aspx), but the output .xml does not have it.

Without RenderingInfo:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System>
      <Provider Name='TestSource'/>
      <EventID Qualifiers='0'>555</EventID>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>1</Task>
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime='2016-04-25T19:17:15.260504300Z'/>
      <EventRecordID>211346</EventRecordID>
      <Channel>TestLog</Channel>
      <Computer>MyComputer</Computer>
      <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data>1</Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
```

With:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System>
      <Provider Name='TestSource'/>
      <EventID Qualifiers='0'>555</EventID>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>1</Task>
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime='2016-04-25T19:17:15.260504300Z'/>
      <EventRecordID>211346</EventRecordID>
      <Channel>TestLog</Channel>
      <Computer>MyComputer</Computer>
      <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data>1</Data>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture='en-US'>
      <Message>1</Message>
      <Level>Information</Level>
      <Task></Task>
      <Opcode>Info</Opcode>
      <Channel></Channel>
      <Provider></Provider>
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword>Classic</Keyword>
      </Keywords>
    </RenderingInfo>
  </Event>
```

I can't seem to find much information about RenderingInfo or how to obtain it.

How can I obtain RenderingInfo using EventLogReader?

What is RenderingInfo and what are some other ways I can get it?

I've been looking into other ways to retrieve events (WMI, WinAPI, EventLog, LogParser.exe) but I'm unsure which solution would get me RendingInfo the fastest.

Comment: From [RenderingInfoType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385200.aspx): *"Only events that have been collected using the [Windows Event Collector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb427443.aspx) service will contain this section."*

Comment: Is this specific to EventLogReader? The events don't come from WEF yet Wevtutil.exe still generates the RenderingInfo.